# Insert LineLegend outside FigurePanel in SciDraw

Tags: plotting, packages, scidraw

I would like to put `LineLegend` outside of `FigurePanel` in `Multipanel` view created in package `SciDraw`.
So far, I came up with one trick that allows me to put `LineLegend` at **specific** location above `FigurePanel`.
Here is my code:

```
 Quiet[Needs["SciDraw`"]];
 (*data and formatting*)
 SeedRandom[1234];
 data1 = Table[{i, Sin[i] + RandomReal[{-.1, .1}]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/100}];
 data2 = Table[{i, Cos[i] + RandomReal[{-.1, .1}]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/100}];
 yrange = {-1.2, 1.2};
 xrange = {0, 2 Pi};
 labelFun[x_, _] := 
 Module[{frac = Rationalize[x/Pi] Pi, num, den}, num = Numerator[frac];
 den = Denominator[frac];
 If[den == 1, num, StringForm["``/``", num, den]]];
 (*formatting*)
 DefineStyle["dat1", {DataLine -> {Show -> False}, DataSymbol -> {SymbolSize -> 5, 
 SymbolShape -> "Diamond", Color -> Red, ShowFill -> True}}];
 DefineStyle["dat2", {DataLine -> {Show -> False}, DataSymbol -> {SymbolSize -> 5, 
 SymbolShape -> "DownTriangle", Color -> Orange, ShowFill -> True}}];

 (*LineLegend*)
 legend = LineLegend[{Directive[Black, Dashed, Thick]}, {Style["curve",Black, 18]}, 
 LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, LabelStyle -> {20}, LegendMarkerSize -> 30, LegendLabel -> 
 Placed[Style["legend: ", Black, 18], Left], LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, 
 FrameMargins -> {{50, 50}, {-12, -12}}, Background -> White, BaseStyle -> White] &)];

 Figure[
 Multipanel[
 {
  FigurePanel[{DataPlot[data1, DataColumns -> {1, 2},Style -> "dat1"], 
  FigGraphics[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed, Thick}]]}, {1, 1},
  XXShowFrameLabel -> True,
  (*trick for inserting legend*)
  XXFrameLabel -> FigLabel[legend, Point -> Scaled[{.22, 1.04}]]],
  (*end of trick*)
  FigurePanel[{DataPlot[data2, DataColumns -> {1, 2}, Style -> "dat2"], 
  FigGraphics[Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed, Thick}]]}, {1, 2}, 
  YShowTickLabels -> True]
  }
  ,Dimensions -> {1, 2}, XPanelGaps -> 0.13, XPlotRange -> xrange, YPlotRange -> yrange, 
  XTicks -> LinTicks[0, 2 Pi, Pi/2, 4, TickLabelFunction -> labelFun],PanelLetter -> 
  None],CanvasSize -> {8, 4}, CanvasMargin -> {{0.4, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.32}}]
```

The trick is in associating `XXFrameLabel` with a `FigLabel`.
[image]

However, I need to put `LineLegend` at specific position (`Scaled[{.22, 1.04}]`), in order to cover error message (e.g. **Object(Removed[Object$769])**) caused by `XXFrameLabel -> FigLabel[legend, Point -> Scaled[{.22, 1.04}]]]`.Here is the picture with error message:
[image]

Does anyone know how one can put `LineLegend` outside panels without creating error message?
I would appreciate any help.